# Hide Bottom Navigation bar from appearing as part of the app?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to create an immersive full screen app. The issue is, when I type something in an edit text and hide the keyboard, a black navigation bar shows up at the bottom of my app permanently. This ends up blocking my elements from view and making my app look awful in general.

I've tried searching for a solution but nothing I find seems to work or I'm possibly not searching for the correct term. I'd prefer if the only type of navigation that showed was overlaid on a swipe up gesture on top of the app instead of becoming part of my app. The code below works great initially to create the full screen immersion I'm looking for but as soon as an EditText is triggered it basically disables.

```
private void hideSystemUI(){
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);


    }
```

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell what's wrong. Maybe checkout the `windowSoftInputMode` (https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility) in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for your activity. This is the only thing I can think of right now which could have an effect.

Comment: I've set the windowSoftInputMode to "Adjust Pan". Really, all it does is affect the way in which the navigation bar that shows up in the app interacts with my Views, it does not adjust that bottom navigation bars visibility.